# How can I determine if a Matrix object in an oct-file contains only integers?

Tags: c++, octave

Say I have some oct-file code like this:

```
bool parseStatus;
octave_value_list out = eval_string(
        "data = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9; 10, 11, 12]", false, parseStatus);
Matrix a_matrix = out(0).matrix_value();
```

The elements of `a_matrix` are essentially integers. Is there a way to determine that programmatically (without comparing the `ceilf` of every element in `a_matrix` to itself)?

Comment: The short answer: no there isn't.

Comment: No, unless the underlying data type of the matrix is an integer - which isn't usually the case. And usually checking the remainder of the value modulo 1 is the way to test if a floating point number represents an integer value.

Comment: @StephenWade is there a modulo method on an octave_value?  Or maybe you mean perform an operation on `data` in the context of octave before returning to the C++ level?

Comment: Looks like there isn't a mod function, but an equivalent to mod(x,y) is x - y * floor(x/y) - and there is certainly a floor method for octave_value.